# How to find what version of file I have now?

Tags: tfs, version-control

I want to know what version of file I have now (TFS). I know about history of file, and in history of file: does arrow at the left side of changeset number say this is effective version of file?

[image: this little arrow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you click the arrow, you'll see there are the changesets from your source branch. This arrow only means it collapses the source branch changesets.

If you want to check the changeset number in your workspace, you can use the following [history command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/history-command?view=azure-devops) from the root (top) of your workspace:

`tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W`

Check the follow blog for more information of this command:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace/

Comment: thank you for the links. This is not exact answer i was looking for but i've found out how to answer my question thanks to you. You provided a way to find the actual version of whole workspace. This is useful when I need to know what version i've got some time ago and i'm working on. But in some cases I need to know the version of the specific file, so I need to modify a little this command prompt line. I will need to do "tf history program.cs /version:W". As I understood, /version:W displays the latest version IN THE WORKSPACE.